# Maximum profit array c++ multiple sell

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, max

Given an array of size `n` which represents prices of an object over `n` days . Each day you have to either buy a single object or you can sell any amount of objects you have to earn money.Assume that you can always buy an object. And you can sell only if you have some objects. So to maximize the total profit you have to choose particular day for selling and buying.

For example ..`N=10 arr={5,0,9,2,9,0,2,7,4,7}`, Now lets say initially total no of objects you have is `n=0;` and total profit `p= 0`
On day 1 you don't have any object so in any case you have to buy one ..
`n=1 , p=-5` and now on day 2 you can buy second one with no amount to spend so `n=2` and `p=-5` on day 3 you can sell both objects and earn money so `n=0` and `p=13`
similarly we can proceed further and maximum profit earned will be `35`

Please help me with this question. I have already seen the problems where we have to choose the days to sell and buy ..but that seem to help me because here you have to either buy or sell each day ..Please give me some idea how to proceed

Comment: Try sorting the list into two groups, high and low, then buy low and sell high.

Comment: @JoeM  can you plz explain what do you mean by sorting the list into two groups ..

Comment: Jared's answer below is along the lines of what I was talking about.

Comment: Hint: Consider the highest price in the array.  (Let's assume for the moment that, unlike in your example, there is a unique day with the maximum price.)  Will you want to buy or sell objects on this day?  If you want to sell, how many would it be best to sell?  (Think about this: if you decided *not* to sell all your objects that day, when would you sell the remaining ones?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker y wud not i decide to sell all the objects on the day which has highest value ..selling all objects on that particular day will always lead to have greater profit

Comment: Exactly.  This gives you a way to break the problem into independent subproblems, if you think about it.  There's still the question of what to do on the preceding days, though.  Can you think of a rule for them?

Comment: And there's also the question of which day to pick as the first "sell-everything" day when there are multiple days with the maximum price.  What's the best strategy here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to keep an average of the price, you could always buy when its below average, and sell when its above average.

You would have to keep a total of each day's price, so 5 for day one and two, 14 for day three and so on.

Then divide it by the number of days passed so far, so 14/3 = 4.66

if the day is greater than the average and you have objects, sell. Otherwise, buy.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's not the optimal strategy though, since it might be that at some later day you can get a much higher sale price, and in that case it would be better to hang onto the objects even if you could get some profit by selling them today.

Comment: Very true, you could add in some functionality that forces you to have a certain difference between the average and the sell price, but if you were to do that, you would want to acctually create an object that knows how much you bought it for, and only sells each object when there is a specific difference between its specific buy price and the sell, but that seemed a bit much for this problem. You are absolutely correct though this is not optimal, it is merely simple